# How do I remove the black translucent overlay over the background when I scale my windows in Linux Mint via editing the codes?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

I know it's caused by themes as some themes has it and some don't. But I really like to keep my mint-Y-Dark theme as it looks awesome. And thus, this question arisen, I know there are some codes to it and editing them will resolve the problem but I don't know what code it is and from where is it in the mint-Y-Dark theme folder. I am using Linux mint 18 Cinnamon.

Here is the desktop; not scaled:
[image: desktop, not scaled]

**Here is the scaled window, notice the tranlucent black overlay:**
[image: scaled window with translucent black overlay]

Comment: What do you mean by “editing the codes”? If you edited some configuration file, tell us which file and copy-paste what you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Mint-Y theme folders:

```
~/.themes/Mint-Y
~/.themes/Mint-Y-Dark
~/.themes/Mint-Y-Darker
```

It should be in ~/.themes/Mint-Y-Dark/cinnamon/cinnamon.css

Please download today's version of the theme:
https://github.com/linuxmint/mint-y-theme/archive/master.zip

Instructions from GitHub on editing:

Do not makes modifications to the theme directly in the usr/share/themes directory. These are automatically generated from the files located in the src/ directory. Each subdirectory contains its own individual instructions on how to edit. Once edits are made you can generate the final themes by running the build-themes.py script.

Best would be a regular update the icons and themes using a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p ~/Downloads/themes-mint/

wget -O ~/Downloads/themes-mint/themes.zip https://github.com/linuxmint/mint-y-theme/archive/master.zip
wget -O ~/Downloads/themes-mint/icons.zip https://github.com/linuxmint/mint-y-icons/archive/master.zip

unzip -o ~/Downloads/themes-mint/themes.zip -d ~/Downloads/themes-mint/
unzip -o ~/Downloads/themes-mint/icons.zip -d ~/Downloads/themes-mint/

cp -r ~/Downloads/themes-mint/mint-y-theme-master/usr/share/themes/* ~/.themes/
cp -r ~/Downloads/themes-mint/mint-y-icons-master/usr/share/icons/* ~/.icons/
```

Save it as a text file in your home directory, name it e.g. `update-themes` and run `chmod 700 update-themes`, then always use it like `./update-themes`.

Comment: Please see my edited post, hopefully it's clearer.

Comment: Opps I forgotten to mentioned the actually mint-Y-Dark

Comment: Sorry, see my edited comment again. It seems that mint-Y and mint-Y-dark for me still gives that overlay but the mint-X series doesn't.